# GraphQL response returning null for specific field in a json object when all other fields have values

Tags: postgresql, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js

So I have a graphql query that fetches all accounts in our API. The resolver fetches the data from our postgres db using a SQL query that joins multiple tables because I need to know which account belongs to what entity (department) and funding (like a loan or grant).
We're using the json operator to create an entity and funding object columns and all the fields are there. However in the response, the id field specifically is returning null. Accounts.id is there but accounts.entity.id and accounts.funding.id return null. However if I query entity.id and funding.id  it returns the correct value. We don't know why. Our schema defines id as a String.

Here is the response:

``
`

```
  "data": {
    "accounts": {
      "docs": [
        {
          "name": "*******************",
          "slugName": "*************************",
          "id": "635********6d1",
          "entity": {
            "id": null,
            "slugName": "**************",
            "address": "0x****************************71C",
            "name": "*****************",
            "type": "*********"
          },
          "funding": {
            "id": null,
            "slugName": "********************************",
            "type": "********",
            "name": "**********"
          }
        },
```

and here is the SQL query:
``
`

```
`select
    account.*,
    to_json(entity.*) as "entity",
    to_json(funding.*) as "funding"
  from account
  left join entity on entity.id=account."entityId"
  left join funding on funding.id=account."fundingId"`
```

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. Maybe you're accidentally assigning `= null` instead of comparing `== null` somewhere? You'll need to do some more debugging yourself as to where exactly the `null` comes up.

Comment: What if `entity.id` and `funding.id` are not strings? They would then be stripped out of the result. Please post the results of `select to_json(entity) limit 1` and `select to_json(funding) limit 1`